# How do I raise an exception in Rspec while running a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have an ActiveRecord Transaction that I am trying to test, but I'm having some difficulty understanding exactly how to write my Rspec test. Here is an example of what I'm going for:

```
it "does not change the model count" do
  expect(Model.count).to be(0)
  expect {
    MyClass.my_method(arg1, arg2)
  }.to raise_error
  expect(Model.count).to be(0)
end
```

While `my_method` is running, there are several objects being saved to the DB. I want to raise an exception *while* this method is running in order to invoke the transaction rollback.

What is the best way to go about raising this exception?

**EDIT:**

I appreciate everyone taking the time to give me input. My goal was to test a transaction rollback. I was calling two different methods inside a transaction, and I wanted to make sure that if an error arose in the second method the data written to the DB in the first method did not persist.

I got this to work as I needed, though I recognize it's contrived.

```
class MyClass

  def self.save_my_values(arg1, arg2)
    parsed = parse(arg1)

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      some_method(parsed, arg2)
      my_method(parsed, arg2)
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the code in the spec:

```
context "when there is an error" do
  before do
    allow(MyClass).to receive(:my_method).and_raise(StandardError)
  end

  it "does not change the model count" do
    expect(Model.count).to be(0)
    expect {
      MyClass.my_method(arg1, arg2)
    }.to raise_error(StandardError)
    expect(Model.count).to be(0)
  end
end
```

I'll be refining it further, but this was the starting point I was looking for. Thank you again!

Comment: The cleanest method is to provide incomplete data, so that one of those objects won't be valid and will refuse to `save!`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this approach violates SRP in testing :) I would go with mocking `save!` to throw `Rollback` and use normal objects then.

Comment: @mudasobwa: your approach, on the other hand, is hardcoding assumptions about underlying implementation. I think it's worse. :)

Comment: "I have an ActiveRecord Transaction that I am trying to test" - the transactions mechanism itself is already thoroughly tested by the rails team, btw.

Comment: @mudasobwa: better to stub _some_ method to raise any error. Still should trigger the rollback.

Comment: @JohnTheSixth: Your question is not clear to me. Your test expects that an error is raised. You shouldn't mock or throw the error yourself in the test, because than you do not test the actual behavior of your code. Instead you should choose `arg1` and `arg2` in a way that it leads `MyClass.my_method` to raise the error. Can you please post the code of your `MyClass.my_method`?

Comment: Updated the above with the solution that worked for me. Everyone, thanks for your input. @spickermann thanks for the suggestion, I'll work on refining the spec.